# while installing phpmyadmin i am getting an error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

while installing phpmyadmin i am getting following error

```
E: Sub-process gzip returned an error code (100)
    E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/php5-gd_5.4.6-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb



   E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/php5-mysql_5.4.6-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
    E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/dbconfig-common_1.8.47+nmu1_all.deb
    E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libmcrypt4_2.5.8-3.1_amd64.deb
    E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/php5-mcrypt_5.4.6-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
    E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/phpmyadmin_4%3a3.4.11.1-1_all.deb
    debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: 
    dpkg: warning: 'sh' not found in PATH or not executable
    dpkg: warning: 'rm' not found in PATH or not executable
    dpkg: warning: 'tar' not found in PATH or not executable
    dpkg: error: 3 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable
    Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to install it. Please specify that. By the way you can try **LAMPP or XAMPP.**

To install it very easily, you can try this:

Download this: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html#374

Go to downloads folder through terminal, or where ever you downloaded it

Then become superuser through command:   **su.**  And then type in your password

```
Then, type this:

tar xvfz xampp-linux-1.8.1.tar.gz -C /opt
```

That's all. XAMPP is now installed below the /opt/lampp directory.

To start XAMPP simply call this command:

**/opt/lampp/lampp start**

You should now see something like this on your screen:

```
Starting XAMPP 1.8.1...
LAMPP: Starting Apache...
LAMPP: Starting MySQL...
LAMPP started.
```

OK, that was easy but how can you check that everything really works? Just type in the following URL at your favourite web browser:

```
<http://localhost
```

If everything went right, you will see a orange screen with all the software installed and PHPMYADMIN will be at the bottom.